# Find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $ {2015}\choose{m} $ is an even number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $$
>  {2015}\choose{m}$$ is an even number.

Since $$
 {{2015}\choose{m}} = \frac{2015}{1} \cdot \frac{2014}{2} \cdots \frac{2016-m}{m} = \prod_{k=1}^m \frac{2016-k}{k}, $$ 
we only need to find the smallest $m$ such that $$ m = 2^{a_m} \cdot p_m, \,  2016-m = 2^{b_m} \cdot q_m, \, 2 \not \mid p_m, \, 2 \not \mid q_m, \, a_m < b_m.$$

In this problem, it turns out that when $m=32$, we have $$ 32=2^5, \, 2016-32=1984=2^6 \cdot 31. $$

However, we will need to try $m=2,4,6,\ldots,32$, the answer will not come out easily.

Is there any easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possibly helpful, possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233269/odd-and-even-numbers-in-pascals-triangle-sierpinskis-triangle

Comment: That's the way I would use, you already have an approach that is optimal in many ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem):

> for given integers $n \ge m \ge 0$ and a prime number $p$, the $p$-adic valuation $\nu _{p}\left({\tbinom {n}{m}}\right)$ is equal to the number of carries when $m$ is added to $n - m$ in base $p$

Since $2015_{10} = 11111011111_2$ it's clear that for any $m < 32$ there will be no carries, and so $\binom{2015}{m}$ will be odd. However, to subtract $32_{10} = 100000_2$ we need to borrow, and therefore adding $32$ and $2015-32$ will require a carry. QED.

Answer (score 2):

for any natural number $n$, let $v_2(n)$ denote the order to which $2$ divides $n$.

It is not difficult to show that $$v_2(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Big \lfloor \frac n{2^i} \Big \rfloor\implies v_2(2015!)=2005$$

It follows that we are asking for the least $k$ such that $$v_2(k!)+v_2((2015-k)!)<2005$$

In searching for such a $k$ it is helpful to note that $2^6\,|\,1984$ and that this is the closest integer less than $2015$ which is divisible by a large power of $2$.  Thus it is reasonable to imagine that we want $k$ such that $2015-k=1983$, so $k=32$.

Note:  This isn't a complete proof, just a strong heuristic to suggest that $32$ is correct.  Given the above, $32$ is the first number I would try...though there is still some work involved in proving that it is minimal.  The inequality shows an easy way to perform the necessary check without heavy computations.

Answer (score 1):

$2016 = 2^5*63$

So $2016 - j_{odd}*2^k= 63*2^5- j_{odd}*2^k$ will be divisible by $2^k$ for all $k <5$ and the terms $\frac {2016-j_{odd}*2^k}{2^k}=63*2^{5-k} - j_{odd}$ will all be odd.

So for any $m < 32$ then ${2015 m} =\frac {2015*2014*2013*2012*.....(2016-m)}{1*2*3*4*.....*m}$ will have to be odd because all the even terms $2014, 2012, 2010, .......$ (which are divisible by $2, 2^2, 2, 2^3, 2, 2^2, 2,2^4, 2, 2^2,2,2^3,2, 2^2, 2....$) are "matched up to be divided" by the even terms, $2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,...$ which are also divisible by  $2, 2^2, 2, 2^3, 2, 2^2, 2,2^4, 2, 2^2,2,2^3,2, 2^2, 2...$.  So each term in the numerator divisible by a power of $2$ is in "lockstep" with a matching power of $2$ is the denominator.

$2016 -32 = 1984$ which is divisible by $32$ but because $2016 = 63*32$ that means $2016-32 = 62*32$ and as $62$ is even we have broken the lockstep and $2016-32$ is divisble not just be $32$ but by $64$.

So ${2015 32} = \frac {2015*2014*2013*2012*2011....... *1983*1984}{1*2*3*4*5......*31 *32} = \frac {2015*1007*2013*503*2011......*1983*62}{1*1*3*1*5*.....*31*1}$ is even.

In general if $2^k|M+1$ and $2^{k+1}\not \mid M$ then $m = 2^k$ will be the least $m$ so that ${M \choose m}$ is even.

Because $M+1 = odd*2^k$ so $M+1 - even_k$ will be "matched" numerator to denominator to $even_k$ up to $M+1 - 2^k = (odd-1)*2^k$ which will be matched to $2^k$.  $\frac {(odd-1)*2^k}{2^k} = odd -1$ is even so the product is even.

=====

Okay,  a more formal proof.

If $n\in \mathbb n$ and $n = a*2^k$ where $a$ is $odd$ and $k\ge 0$ then define $f(n) =a$ and $g(n) = 2^k$.

${2015 \choose m} =\frac {\prod_{i=1}^m (2016-i)}{\prod_{i=1}^m i}=$

$\frac {\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m (2016-m)\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m (2016-i)}{\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m i\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m i}=$

$\frac {\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m (2016-i)\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m (2016-i)}{\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m i\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m f(i)\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m g(i)}=$

$\frac {\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m (2016-i)\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m (2016-m)}{\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m i\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m f(i)}*\frac {\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m (2016-f(i)g(i))}{\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m g(i)}=$

$\frac {\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m (2016-i)\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m (2016-m)}{\prod_{i=1;i\text{ odd}}^m i\prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m f(i)}* \prod_{i=1;i\text{ even}}^m  (63*\frac{32}{\min(32,g(i))}-f(i)$

Which will be odd if and only if all the $(63*\frac{32}{\min(32,g(i))}-f(i))$ terms are odd for all even $i$.

If $g(i) < 32$ then $(63*\frac{32}{\min(32,g(i))}-f(i))= 63\frac {32}{g(i)} - f(i)$ is odd.  If $g(i) \ge 32$ then $(63*\frac{32}{\min(32,g(i))}-f(i))= 63 - f(i)$ is even.

So ${2015 \choose m}$ is odd if and only if $g(i) < 32$ for all $i \le m$ if and only if $m < 32$.

Answer (score 1):

for the curious, 32 is correct. Wrote a command for Legendre's rule. Now that I think about it, this leads to a method for doing this by hand, based on a proof of Legendre by induction that I once posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n/228351#228351   Give me a few minutes. In brief, 
$$  \nu_p((n+1)!) =  \nu_p(n!) + \nu_p(n+1)  \; .  $$
Yes. As some of the other answers have already indicated, we are searching for integer $j$ with
$$ \nu_2(j+1) < \nu_2(2015-j) \; , $$
after which the answer is $m=j+1.$ Then
$$ 5 = \nu_2(31+1) < \nu_2(2015 - 31) = \nu_2(1984) = \nu_2 (64 \cdot 31)=6  $$

========================================================

```
Sat Aug  4 11:40:24 PDT 2018
1 j+1 2  2 order:   1    2015 - j 2014 order: 1
2 j+1 3  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2013 order: 0
3 j+1 4  2 order:   2    2015 - j 2012 order: 2
4 j+1 5  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2011 order: 0
5 j+1 6  2 order:   1    2015 - j 2010 order: 1
6 j+1 7  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2009 order: 0
7 j+1 8  2 order:   3    2015 - j 2008 order: 3
8 j+1 9  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2007 order: 0
9 j+1 10  2 order:   1    2015 - j 2006 order: 1
10 j+1 11  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2005 order: 0
11 j+1 12  2 order:   2    2015 - j 2004 order: 2
12 j+1 13  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2003 order: 0
13 j+1 14  2 order:   1    2015 - j 2002 order: 1
14 j+1 15  2 order:   0    2015 - j 2001 order: 0
15 j+1 16  2 order:   4    2015 - j 2000 order: 4
16 j+1 17  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1999 order: 0
17 j+1 18  2 order:   1    2015 - j 1998 order: 1
18 j+1 19  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1997 order: 0
19 j+1 20  2 order:   2    2015 - j 1996 order: 2
20 j+1 21  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1995 order: 0
21 j+1 22  2 order:   1    2015 - j 1994 order: 1
22 j+1 23  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1993 order: 0
23 j+1 24  2 order:   3    2015 - j 1992 order: 3
24 j+1 25  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1991 order: 0
25 j+1 26  2 order:   1    2015 - j 1990 order: 1
26 j+1 27  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1989 order: 0
27 j+1 28  2 order:   2    2015 - j 1988 order: 2
28 j+1 29  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1987 order: 0
29 j+1 30  2 order:   1    2015 - j 1986 order: 1
30 j+1 31  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1985 order: 0
31 j+1 32  2 order:   5    2015 - j 1984 order: 6  WOW  
32 j+1 33  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1983 order: 0
33 j+1 34  2 order:   1    2015 - j 1982 order: 1
34 j+1 35  2 order:   0    2015 - j 1981 order: 0
35 j+1 36  2 order:   2    2015 - j 1980 order: 2
Sat Aug  4 11:40:24 PDT 2018
```

=============================================================

```
Sat Aug  4 10:57:09 PDT 2018
2015 two order: 2005

1 order: 0     2014 order: 2005 sum    2005
2 order: 1     2013 order: 2004 sum    2005
3 order: 1     2012 order: 2004 sum    2005
4 order: 3     2011 order: 2002 sum    2005
5 order: 3     2010 order: 2002 sum    2005
6 order: 4     2009 order: 2001 sum    2005
7 order: 4     2008 order: 2001 sum    2005
8 order: 7     2007 order: 1998 sum    2005
9 order: 7     2006 order: 1998 sum    2005
10 order: 8     2005 order: 1997 sum    2005
11 order: 8     2004 order: 1997 sum    2005
12 order: 10     2003 order: 1995 sum    2005
13 order: 10     2002 order: 1995 sum    2005
14 order: 11     2001 order: 1994 sum    2005
15 order: 11     2000 order: 1994 sum    2005
16 order: 15     1999 order: 1990 sum    2005
17 order: 15     1998 order: 1990 sum    2005
18 order: 16     1997 order: 1989 sum    2005
19 order: 16     1996 order: 1989 sum    2005
20 order: 18     1995 order: 1987 sum    2005
21 order: 18     1994 order: 1987 sum    2005
22 order: 19     1993 order: 1986 sum    2005
23 order: 19     1992 order: 1986 sum    2005
24 order: 22     1991 order: 1983 sum    2005
25 order: 22     1990 order: 1983 sum    2005
26 order: 23     1989 order: 1982 sum    2005
27 order: 23     1988 order: 1982 sum    2005
28 order: 25     1987 order: 1980 sum    2005
29 order: 25     1986 order: 1980 sum    2005
30 order: 26     1985 order: 1979 sum    2005
31 order: 26     1984 order: 1979 sum    2005
32 order: 31     1983 order: 1973 sum    2004 WOW 
33 order: 31     1982 order: 1973 sum    2004 WOW 
34 order: 32     1981 order: 1972 sum    2004 WOW 
35 order: 32     1980 order: 1972 sum    2004 WOW 
Sat Aug  4 10:57:09 PDT 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

$n = 2015_{10} = 11111011111_2$ and from [Luca's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem):

$${2015 \choose m} = \prod_{i=0}^{10} {n_i \choose m_i} \pmod 2$$

where all factors are always $1$ except for ${0 \choose m_5}$ which is $0$ if and only if $m_5 = 1$.

The smallest number having $m_5 = 1$ is $32$.

Generally speaking ${n \choose m}$ is odd if and only if $m \land n = m$, and even otherwise, where $\land$ is meant here as a bitwise operation on binary digits. In other words ${n \choose m}$ is odd if and only if all $1$s in $m$ are $1$ also in $n$.